# Как создать объект сторонней библиотеки используя JNA

Tags: java, dll, jna

Не могу разобраться как создать объект из библиотеки dll.

```java
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLong;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;
import com.sun.jna.*;

public class TestVertical
{
    public interface simpleDLL extends Library
    {    
        simpleDLL INSTANCE = (simpleDLL) Native.loadLibrary("vkernel.dll", simpleDLL.class);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        simpleDLL sdll = simpleDLL.INSTANCE;
        public sdll.IVModel model = new sdll.IVModel();
    }
}
```

в описании API библиотеки "vkernel.dll" есть класс IVModel. Каким образом возможно создать объект model указанного типа?

```
public sdll.IVModel model = new sdll.IVModel();
```

не работает.

Comment: Что такое Library?

Comment: Да, совсем забыл написать: 'import com.sun.jna.Library; 
    import com.sun.jna.Native;
    import com.sun.jna.NativeLong;
    import com.sun.jna.Platform;
    import com.sun.jna.*;'

Comment: Что означает второй параметр?